# Can we integrate C++ dll directly into ionic framework

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

E.g.
We have algorithm part that in C++ dll.

```
Name of C++ dll = test.dll

Header file = test.h
```

Functions exposed in dll-

```
int testfns();
```

Then, In ionic framework source, we will have callback
E.g. Something like this will be in ionic framework -

```
testfns_callback()
{
    int ret_testfns = testfns();
}
```

Is this possible? how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DLL (Dynamic Link Library) is Microsoft's implementation of the C/C++ shared library concept. 
Normally they are compiled to Windows bytecode so can't just be used on a mobile operating system such as Android or iOS.

To run the same C/C++ code on Android and iOS, one would normally cross-compile the source code to a Shared Object (SO) library.

You can see [a comparison of DLL vs SO](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13501/Platform-Independent-Coding-DLLs-and-SOs).

I have created an [example plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c) and associated [test project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c-test) which illustrates how a C/C++ library can be cross-compiled and used in a Cordova environment to run on both Android and iOS platforms.